# How to pass an unknown list of environment variables to a command in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dynamic, environment-variables, rancher

I have a very long and often changing list of environment variables which I need to pass to the same Docker image when starting it. These environment variables are configured in a Rancher environment and will be passed individually as such. They should all be passed to the command that is about to start within the image.

When I had just a few parameters it was possible to pass them while having them explicitly declared in the Dockerfile:

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "node src/server.js --param1=$ENV_PARAM_1"  --param2=$ENV_PARAM_2 ...  --paramN=$ENV_PARAM_N"" ]
```

Now this is not possible anymore because the list has grown to far and is dynamically changing a lot. I also can't build a new image per usecase.

I need something like:

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "node src/server.js $PRINT_ALL_MY_PARAMS_HERE" ]
```

Side note: The command will fail when providing command arguments that are unknown to the command.

**Any idea how I could solve this?**

Answer (score 2):

You can override `CMD` when you run the container.  Say you've built an image with a default command

```sh
CMD node src/server.js
```

When you go to actually run the container, you can override this with whatever you want

```sh
docker run \
  -d -p ... \
  my/image \
  node src/server.js --param1=$ENV_PARAM_1 --param2=$ENV_PARAM_2 ...
```

As I've written it here the `$ENV_PARAM_N` will be resolved by the host system's shell, but if a tool is launching the container for you that might not be a problem.  If some of the values are from Dockerfile `ENV` directives you'll need to force the container shell to do the expansion

```
docker run \
  -d -p ... \
  -e ENV_PARAM_2=not-in-the-dockerfile \
  my/image \
  sh -c 'node src/server.js --param1=$ENV_PARAM_1 --param2=$ENV_PARAM_2 ...'
```

There's also a [pattern](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint) of using the `ENTRYPOINT` as the main program to run and using `CMD` only for additional options.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "src/server.js"]
CMD []
```

```sh
docker run \
  -d -p ... \
  my/image \
  --param1=$ENV_PARAM_1 --param2=$ENV_PARAM_2 ...
```

However, note in this case that you cannot ask the container shell to expand things for you.  `ENTRYPOINT` *must* use the JSON-array syntax, and you can't insert an `sh -c` anywhere in this command usefully.  (`sh -c command` consumes only a single shell "word" as its command, and any other options you write after that will generally get ignored.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to define the part that should always be there when launching the container and CMD for the part that is overridden by command given at container launch:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "node src/server.js"]
CMD ["--param1=$ENV_PARAM_1", "--param2=$ENV_PARAM_2",...  "--paramN=$ENV_PARAM_N"]
```

This way you can have different parameters for each run:

```
docker run server # Executes ENTRYPOINT + CMD from Dockerfile
docker run server --help # Executes ENTRYPOINT + "--help"
```